# How to rewrite "domain/1*" on Joomla website

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I had an old website with pages which had "1" as first symbol.
For example, 
www.example.com/1antony.aspx

www.example.com/1tommy.aspx

I moved website to Joomla and I cannot redirect those pages as they appear as home page on the new website. I noticed this problem on all of my Joomla websites.
Everywhere I use "RewriteBase /" in htaccess.

Is it a bug or how to fix it?

Comment: Can you add the exact RewriteRule you're using? And also, can you add an example of a new URL  (i.e. where should "1antony.aspx" be redirected to?)

Comment: I use basic Joomla companent "redirect" and standart htaccess which comes with Joomla, with unchecked (from #) "RewriteBase /". I tried few RewriteRules but joomla ignores it and place on home page. It happens only with symbol "1", other symbols are fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: RewriteRule ^1tommy$ "http://example.com/olduser/23-1tommy" [R=301,L]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've noticed that I had article with ID 1. I created copy with ID over 100 and deleted all articles from 1 to 9, now it redirects correctly. It seems that when you type in number joomla calls article with that ID number. And the webpage looked like the homepage because all modules were present, but I disabled materials on my homepage.

Hope this helps.